# Change form input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input

I am trying to change the input value of a hidden form to update the score of a game in my database.

I have this form code on a php page that displays and plays the game.

```
<form id ="recordForm" method="POST" action="updatePHP.php">
        <input type='hidden' name="record" id='record' value='' />
 </form>
```

And am trying to change the value of the hidden input field with this javascript.  This is in the separate javascript file that is controlling the game.

```
function postPHP(newRecord){
alert("POST TO PHP");  //test to make sure I am calling this function
alert (newRecord);  //alerts the correct value

var elem = document.getElementById('record');
elem.value = 12;
//    document.getElementById('record').value = newRecord;
//    document.getElementById('recordForm').submit();
};
```

There are a lot of topics on this subject but I am just not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, I have lot of suggestions..... :)

Comment: That code should work fine (it will set the value to `12`). What is your exact problem? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Where you are calling function `postPHP()`

Comment: [check your working code](http://jsfiddle.net/kg3EG/)

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
elem.value = newRecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS function should work like this, i tested, more less what you already have. I remove the alerts since you don't need them anymore and leave what you have commented. This means your JS function isn't the problem.

```
function postPHP(newRecord)
{

document.getElementById('record').value = newRecord;
document.getElementById('recordForm').submit();

};
```

Don't forget to sent the parameter when calling the JS function, i did it with a button

```
<button onClick="postPHP('14')">Change</button>
```

since your JS function is in a separate file don't forget to include it in the File where you call the function

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH/exampleName.js"></script>
</head>
```

Replace the src of the above tag to your needs

And last but not least check your updatePHP.php with a call to the method print_r

```
print_r($_POST);
```

All that should make the trick

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions! This was my first question ever, I will look at all of them and see if I can get it working.

This is where I am calling postPHP:

```
    function checkScore(score, record) {       

        alert('Score= ' + score);
        alert ('Record= '+ record);

        if(score < record || record === 0){
            alert ("NEW RECORD");  //this alert is displayed when needed
            postPHP(score);
        }
};
```

and checkScore was called when the user moved a target crate back to the beginning spot and the following statement was executed

```
        if (this.hasWon()) {
            var finalScore = this.getScore();
            var record = this.getRecord();
            checkScore(finalScore, record);
            return ret;     //moving not allowed
        }
```

there are some access methods used there.

```
    //access methods
    Board.prototype.hasWon = function() {
        return state === 1;
    };
    Board.prototype.getScore = function() {
        return score;
    };
    Board.prototype.getWt = function(r, c) {
        return b[r][c];
    };
    Board.prototype.getData = function() {
        return {"bobR": bobR, "bobC": bobC, "bobDir": bobDir,
            "tgtR": tgtR, "tgtC": tgtC,
            "startC": startC, "n": n};
    };
    Board.prototype.getRecord = function(){
        var s = "" + window.location;
        var ampIdx = "" + s.indexOf("&");
        ampIdx = parseInt(ampIdx);
        ampIdx = ampIdx + 7;

        var record = "" + s.substring(ampIdx);
        //alert("Puzzle Record= " + record);
        record = parseInt(record);
        return record;
    }
    ;
```

I do have the javascript included.  I do call it once in the body of the HTML, for some reason it doesn't display the game correctly when included in the head.

Again, thank you for the help! I will let you know what I get to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got to work.

```
function postPHP(newRecord, seed) {
   alert("POST TO PHP");
   var inner = "<input type='hidden' name='record' id='record' value=" + newRecord + " >"+
                "<input type='hidden' name='seed' id='seed' value=" + seed + " >";
    document.getElementById('recordForm').innerHTML = inner;
    document.getElementById('recordForm').submit();
};
```

Thanks again for all the help, I just don't know why the first method wasn't working. This is my first attempts at PHP and javascript.